# Form Plugin for Api Requests which is used via Shortcode

Tags: plugins, shortcode, forms

I've a little PHP Script with a input Form which is used to register for a newsletter. This Form accepts only an email address and then makes an api call using curl.

Now I wan't to build this form as a plugin for wordpress. It should be easy usable on different pages with a shortcode. I have already build this plugin. I have a Form and I can display this form with the Shortcode. But I don't know how build the functions from my original php file in wordpress. I don't know how to send the form to itself and work with the values. Also I need to work with get parameters which are used to confirm a user.

Here is my original script, I think it's much easier to understand what I wan't to do:

index.php:

```
    <?php

    require_once('functions.php');

    // task subscribe

        if(isset($_POST['task'])){
            $task = $_POST['task'];
            if ($task == "subscribe"){
                if(!empty($_POST['email'])){
                    $email      = $_POST['email'];
                    $group      = basic;

                    $data = array(
                        "group"       => $group,
                        "email"       => $email
                    );
                    $response = doCurlRequest($task, $data);
                }
            }
        }

    // task = confirm

        if(isset($_GET['task']) && isset($_GET['hash'])){
            $task = $_GET['task'];
            $hash = $_GET['hash'];

            $data = array("hash" => $hash);  

            $response = doCurlRequest($task, $data);
        }

    // send mail with confirm link

        if(isset($response['subscriptions']['0'])){

            $to = $response['email'];
            $title = "confirm your address";
            $from = "From: Newslettersystem <newsletter@domain.tld>";
            $text = "
                Please confirm your address: http://domain.tld/index.php?task=confirm&hash=".$response['subscriptions']['0']['hash']."
            ";

            mail($to, $title, $text);

        }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Newsletter Form Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Newsletter Form</h1>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" name="newsletterForm">
            <input type="hidden" name="task" value="subscribe">
            <div>
                <label for="email">E-Mail Adresse *</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="absenden">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

functions.php:

```
function doCurlRequest($task, $data){

    $data_string = json_encode($data);

    // Get cURL resources
    $curl = curl_init();

    // Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://domain.tld/api/emailing/v0.1/'.$task,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Wordpress Form cURL Request',
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length:' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
    ));

    // Send the request & save response to $resp
    $resp = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);

    // Close request to clear up some resources
    curl_close($curl);

    return $resp;

}
```

Okay, that's the original script which is working. And here is my starting point for wordpress:

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: NewsletterFormConnector
 * Description: Newsletter Form to connect to Newsletter Api
 * Author: emjay
 * Version: 1.0
 */

    function addCustomQueryVars( $vars ){
        $vars[] = "task";
        $vars[] = "hash";
        return $vars;
    }

    add_filter( 'query_vars', 'addCustomQueryVars' );

    function createForm(){

        $task = get_query_var( 'task' );
        $hash = get_query_var( 'hash' );

        $form  ="";

        $form .= '<form>';
        $form .= 'E-Mail: <input type="text" name="email">';
        $form .= '</form>';

        return $form;

    }

    add_shortcode('newsletterForm', 'createForm');

?>
```

I hope someone could give me some hints, how I can do this with a shortcode plugin. The shortcode should work on every page and the form is send to itself to make the api calls. But also I need that the page with a Form is responding to GET Parameters from the url so that a user can confirm it's address.

Thanks for your help,

emjay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a function to process the form. In the shortcode function, first process the form and then return any form/message that you want to display to the user.

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: NewsletterFormConnector
 * Description: Newsletter Form to connect to Newsletter Api
 * Author: emjay
 * Version: 1.0
 */

//Add function file
require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'functions.php');

//Add query var
function addCustomQueryVars( $vars ){
    $vars[] = "task";
    $vars[] = "hash";
    return $vars;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'addCustomQueryVars' );

//Helper function to get current page url. You can put it in functions.php
//This is needed when sending message as the confirm page link needs to come to this page as well.
function current_page_url() {
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if( isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ) {
        if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
    }
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL;
}
//Shortcode function
function createForm(){
    //first process the form submit or confirm email task
    process();

    //All the task taken care of, now create html form and return it.

    $form  ="";

    $form .= '<form>';
    $form .= 'E-Mail: <input type="text" name="email">';
    $form .= '</form>';

    return $form;

}

add_shortcode('newsletterForm', 'createForm');

function process() {
    //Process post request
    if( isset($_POST['task']) ) {
        ....
        ....
        //I believe you can complete the process of send mail here
        if(isset($response['subscriptions']['0'])){
            ...
            ...
            $text = "
            Please confirm your address: " . current_page_url() . "?task=confirm&hash=".$response['subscriptions']['0']['hash']."
        ";
            //Send mail with wp_mail instead
            wp_mail($to, $title, $text, $from);
        }
        //Return to shortcode function
        return;
    }

    //Get query variables
    $task = get_query_var('task');
    $hash = get_query_var('hash');
    if( !empty($task) && !empty($hash){
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey :) Thanks for your great suggestions, I will try it out and come back to you later. Thanks!